# Python - Interpolating a gap in scattered data points

Tags: python, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate a gap I have between data points. The data I have is 2 arrays of time and acceleration. The acceleration array consist of values that can be considered periodic. The original data points with the gap look like this:
data points with gap

[image: data points with gap]

I am trying to do the interpolation by using the scipy.interpolate.interp1d as illustrated below:

```
interpolation_func = interpolate.interp1d(time, acceleration, 
kind='slinear')
new_time = np.arange(np.min(time), np.max(time), 0.1)
new_acc = interpolation_func(new_time)
plt.figure(2, figsize=(14, 8))
plt.title('Interpolated uncalibrated acceleration data')
plt.scatter(new_time, new_acc, c=new_time[:], s=1, vmin=np.min(new_time), 
vmax=np.max(new_time))
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Acceleration')
plot_fig2 = (output_folder + "kinematic_plot2.png")
plt.savefig(plot_fig2)
```

However, the result I'm getting is not accurate because I'm get a line that connects the last point from 1st group of scattered points, on the left side of the gap, and the first point from the 2nd group of points, on the right side of the gap. The wrong result looks like this:

Wrong result

[image: Wrong result]

I have tried other options from the scipy.interpolate.interp1d function, other than the kind slinear, but all of them would flatten the scattered points on both sides of the gap and fill in the gap with a polynomial graph, which is not what I need. Are there any options in python to interpolate the gap I have between the scattered points?

Comment: In the example above, are you expecting 3 lines instead of just 1?

Comment: Also, it looks like the data has an oscillation pattern. Are you expecting the interpolation to detect that pattern as well?

Comment: You do not need a straight line, you do not need a polynomial, what do you need then?

Comment: Yes the data has an oscillation pattern. What I need is 1 line that will detect the pattern of the data and fill in the gap with data points, that follow the same pattern, through interpolation.